# Windows batch script - comparing strings in if statement

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a Windows batch script which examines an XML file (the iml file) to search for a certain line,  .  I am having trouble with the spaces in the string.  Is there a way to escape or compensate for the spaces?

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (abcd.iml) do (
    echo %%a
    if %%a==^<orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" ^> (echo 'FOUND')
 )
```

Comment: You should always use quotes with string comparisons. `if "%%a"=="<orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" >" `

Comment: …and `(echo 'FOUND'^)`.

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187112/how-to-use-the-set-function-in-a-batch-script-to-accept-spaces/35188244#35188244) and [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282362/batch-cmd-exits-as-i-enter-the-input-with-space/48282847#48282847)

Answer (score 1):

Put the %%a in quotes so it is like "%%a." Instead of using the "==" operator to compare %%a and "^" it would be better to use the EQU comparator so the final code would look like:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (abcd.iml) do (
    echo %%a
    if "%%a" EQU "<orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" >" (echo 'FOUND')
 )
```

For more information on EQU and other operators see https://ss64.com/nt/if.html or https://ss64.com/nt/equ.html

Comment: Neko Musume, I think that you should have read Sqashman's opening comment, and [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396292/windows-batch-script-comparing-strings-in-if-statement#comment108611823_61396292) too, because currently, _(despite the upvote you've already received)_ your answer doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Oh do you mean the breakout key on the echo? Sorry I never really understood how to use it but I can edit the answer and add it.

Comment: Please read the comments! and obviously if you get the chance test it yourself. It wouldn't take much to test it against any file, renamed accordingly with and without inserting the required string `<orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" >` on a line.

Comment: It already works for me, I've tested it so I don't know what errors you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

no need for a `for` loop. A simple `findstr` is much faster:

```
 findstr /c:"<orderEntry type=\"inheritedJdk\" >" "abcd.iml" >nul && echo found || echo nope
```

Note: the quotes within the string have to be escaped (escape character for `findstr` is a backslash)

Comment: Wouldn't "findstr" be better for searching for text in files?

Comment: @NekoMusume `findstr` is newer and has more options, but `find` is perfectly fine for some tasks, so newer is not always better. But you are right in this case. The quotes in the string have to be escaped. `Find` can't do that (my previous `find` solution ran fine just "by accident" (was satisfied by just `<orderEntry type=` and ignored the rest)). Changed to `findstr`.